# Need ideas/advices about a database structure

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

Let's think we have 100+ hotels, and each hotel has at least more than 3 room types.
I want to hold hotel's capacity for one year in the past and one year in the future. How should i design the database for *easiest use*.

Example:

> A hotel has 30 rooms. 10 x "Standard
>   room", 10 x "Duplex Room", 10 x "Delux
>   room" I will keep this example on
>   standard rooms. Today is: 13.01.2011 I
>   want to keep records from 13.01.2010
>   to 13.01.2012 What i will store in
>   database is available rooms. Something
>   like this(for standard room):
>
> > 13.01.2011: 10
> >
> > 14.01.2011: 9 (means 1 standard room sold for this day)
> >
> > 15.01.2011: 8 (means 2 standard rooms sold for this day)
> >
> > 16.01.2011: 10 (all available for this day)
> >
> > 17.01.2011: 7 (means 3 standard rooms sold for this day)
> >
> > 18.01.2011: 10

etc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is either a non-question, or your understanding is so limited that you're not even asking the right question. A database isn't designed for easiest use. It's designed to store the data efficiently and ensure integrity of the data and searchability. The user interface that access the data is what needs to be easy to use.  And your examples have nothing to do with a database structure. It's a delimited string.

Comment: "easiest use" may be my bad. Anyway i will need the best form for storing them. And sorry, i didn't get what you mean by "nothing to do with a database structure" and "delimited string".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to summarize your question to see if I understand it properly:

> You have a set of Hotels. Each Hotel
>   has a set of Rooms. Each Room belongs
>   to one of a number of possible Room
>   Types. The lowest level of detail
>   we're interested in here is a Room.

This suggests a table of Hotels, a lookup table of Room Types, and a table of Rooms: each Room will have a reference to its associated Hotel and Room Type.

> For any given day, a room is either
>   booked (sold) or not booked (let's
>   leave off partial days for simplicity
>   at this point). For each day in the
>   year before and the year after the
>   current day, you wish to know how many
>   rooms of each type were available (non-booked) at
>   each hotel.

Now, since hotels need to be able to look at bookings individually, it's likely you would maintain a table of bookings. But these would typically be defined by a Room, a Start Date, and a number of Nights, which isn't ideal for your stated reporting purposes: it isn't broken down by day.

So you may wish to maintain a "Room Booking Log" table, which simply contains a record for each room booked on each day: this could be as simple as a datestamp column plus a Room ID.

This sort of schema would let you generate the output you're describing relatively easily via aggregate queries (displaying the sum of rooms booked per day, grouped by hotel and room type, for example). The model also seems like it would lend itself to an [OLAP cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olap_cube).

Comment: | room_id | hotel_id | date | count_we_have | this will generate (if we have 150 hotels and 3 room types each, 150*3*(365*2)=328500 lines, is it ok? each room type will add 730 new lines? did i understand right?

Comment: I assume the first column in your example should be `room_type_id`? Adding a room type to that equation would add 730 records *per hotel*, i.e. ~100000 records. "Is it ok?" doesn't really have a canonical answer, but 300-400k records, if queried and indexed appropriately, isn't unreasonable for a professional DBMS to handle (in my non-expert opinion). Obviously, **be careful** if you end up adding large numbers of room types or many more years of data, as the table's size will increase rapidly...

Answer (score 0):

I did a homework question like this once.  Basically you need at least 3 tables: one which holds the rooms, one which holds the reservations, and another table that links the too because its not a specific room that is reserved at a given time, its a specific type of room.